# Using JS to do a redirect in a Content Management System if criteria is met

Tags: javascript, if-statement, redirect, content-management-system

I am working in a CMS and I am using an html widget to do some redirect code, it is working fine, but of course there is a wrinkle. Basically, I want to create an if statement, because there is a possible message on the initial page. So what I want it to do is if it doesn't see the div - redirect, but if it does see the div, do nothing.

```
var msgDiv = document.getElementById('thisDiv');

if (msgDiv === null) {
   window.location = "otherpage.html";
} else {
  //do nothing
}
```

What is happening with this code, is it goes right into redirect regardless. If I do this version:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var msgDiv= document.getElementById('thisDiv');

    if (msgDiv === null) {
       window.location = "otherpage.html";
    } else {
      //do nothing
    }

};
```

I briefly see the first page and the message, but then it redirects just after a pause. I feel like I am missing one small detail and would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: So how many `id` 's does this element have? In the first example you use `thisDiv` and in the second you use `testDiv`. Is it possible your typo is working exactly the way you've coded it?

Comment: oops, sorry, I am stripping the code a bit, that was a placeholder name. It should be the same in both.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly this should work:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var msgDiv= document.querySelectorAll('#testDiv');

    if (msgDiv.length === 0) {
       window.location = "otherpage.html";

    } else {
      //do nothing
    }

};
```

[Demo](https://bru02.000webhostapp.com/editor/index.php?id=5293015)

Comment: thanks for your response. It is still does a brief stay and then popping on over to the redirect.